# Integrate mysql in waterfall async

Tags: mysql, node.js, waterfall

I need to save to db inside an async waterfall series.

I've tried to integrate these two function after the clean function

```
        function connectDb(next) {
                pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                  if (err) console.log(err);
                    conn = connection;
                }, next);
            },
        function saveDb(next) {
                let sql = "UPDATE media SET media_url = ? WHERE media_url = ?";
                conn.query(sql, [dstKey, srcKey], function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        conn.release();
                        console.log(error);
                    }else{
                        console.log("media db updated");
                    }
                }, next)
            }
```

The problem is that these two functions block the code execution. How can I integrate it in the function below? I've tried to wrap the function in promise but it is also not working.

```
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            s3.getObject({
                    //param
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            resizeMedia(response.Body ).then( ( file ) => { next();} ).catch( (err) => { reject(err) } ); }
        },
        function upload(next) {
            var fileData = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/'+dstKey);

            if (isVideo ) { var ContentType = 'video/mp4' }
            if (isAudio ) { var ContentType = 'audio/mp3' }            

            s3.putObject({
                    //param
                },
                next);
            },            
        function clean(next) {
            // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
            fs.unlinkSync('/tmp/'+dstKey);

            s3.deleteObject({
                    //param
                },
                next);

            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error');
                callback(null, "Error");
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('Success');
                callback(null, "Done");
                return;
            }

            callback(null, "Done");
            return;
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, if someone fall into the same issue here my solution:

If a waterfall function has a response, this response is automatically added as first argument in the next function. In my code the mistake was simple (after night's sleep), the s3.deleteObject and s3.putObject has response, this response need to be setted as first argument and the callback as last, as you say I've used only the callback as argument (next) and this broke my code.

```
[...]

 function upload(next) {

            s3.putObject({
                    //param
                },
                next);
            },            
        function clean(response, next) { // response in arguments

            s3.deleteObject({
                    //param
                },
                next);

            }

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of async waterflow is to block the `waterfall` until the callback is called.

P.S. Usually you should not create a new db connection each time. The connection should be done once when the application start and get used whenever you need.

I highly recommend you to use [knex.js](https://knexjs.org/) instead, it return promises by default and if you like to use it inside async waterfall (and wait for resolve) you can call `.asCallback`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm not create connection each time, this entire function need only this db connection and query, this is a function triggered from s3 just for compress video. Now I'm going to watch knex. Tnx

Comment: Knex is holding the connection pool until you terminate it, if it's a cloud function it could be better to use the mysql library. Anyway I don't see what is your issue.

Comment: My issue is that if I add after clean(next){} another function the code stop working and the lambda function terminate with "Process exited before completing request"

Comment: Try to run only the query function, just to make sure that your code really working, anyway change the final callback to log the full error to console so you will know what happened.

Comment: Hi yeya, thank you, I've found the problems (see my self-answer)